# performance testing for backend Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance-testing

I have a Rails app that sends multiple requests both sequentially and in parallel to a third-party API and do calculation in the backend.

I would like to know how long each of my API requests and calculation takes. Is there performance testing gem I should use?

Note: my app uses Sidekiq to process backend jobs.

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html might get you started, check out section 3 for details of wrapping methods in "benchmark" which outputs some useful stats to the log.

As a quick example:

```
def process
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report("Processing Task") do 
      process_task(task_options)
    end
  end
end
```

would output something like:

```
                 user       system     total    real
Processing Task  8.206000   1.092000   9.298000 ( 14.609000)
```